# Does a 4 dimensional objects have Hypervolume AND regular volume?

Tags: geometry, volume

Do 4 dimensional objects have
2D surface are, 3d volume, 4d hypervolume
or 3d surface area and 4d hypervolume/volume?

Comment: Something like a ball in $\Bbb R^4$ will have a $4$-volume, and also a boundary which will have a $3$-volume (compare a ball in $\Bbb R^3$)

Comment: Was $\Bbb supposed to make a character or just format R^4 and R^3?

Comment: Does a 3D cube have volume and area?

Comment: The answer is **yes**.

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Ivan Neretin, yes it does, surface area and volume

Comment: Then a 4D object has 3d surface area and 4d hypervolume.

Comment: I have done some work on a 4D right pyramid - It has a "surface" which may be formulated with 5 3D pyramids - each having 4 2d triangles as surface.